# Остановка потока

Tags: многопоточность, java

Ребята, есть тред, в котором есть около 100 методов. Которые в свою очередь идет минут по 10. Такой себе тестовый фрейм.

```
Thread testRunningThread = null;
```

и вызов

```
testRunningThread = new Thread(util);
testRunningThread.start();
```

Остановка проходит так

```
if (testRunningThread != null) {
    util.setInterruptTests(new AtomicBoolean(true));
}
```

Но очень надо тред остановить немедленно. Не дожидаясь окончания конца роботы текещего выполняемого метода. Как ее провести?

Comment: делать проверки чаще?

Comment: нет проверок. Юзер захочет просто остановить выполненине.И тогда нужен немедленный выход.

Comment: Нужно делать методы короче и делать проверки "нужно ли выйти" чаще.

Либо использовать interrupt (читать большую статью на [эту тему](http://www.forward.com.au/javaProgramming/HowToStopAThread.html)).

Comment: Вы _не имеете права_ останавливать поток. Он может находиться в любой фазе выполнения, например, в нативном коде, держащем глобальную блокировку heap-памяти. Поток должен сотрудничать: останавливаться сам, реагировать быстрее на запрос прекратить работу.

---
Юзеру нет дела до того, жив поток или мёртв. Если он хочет завершить приложение, закройте все окна и дожидайтесь окончания работы потоков без UI.

Answer (score 2):

Цитирую со [skipy.ru/technics/synchronization.html](http://www.skipy.ru/technics/synchronization.html):

> Вариант первый – использовать существующий механизм. У класса Thread есть такой метод – interrupt. Этот метод выставляет некоторый флаг в дебрях native-кода. В дальнейшем состояние этого флага можно проверить с помощью метода isInterrupted. Существует также статический метод interrupted, который производит проверку для текущего потока. Обратите внимание – вызов этого метода сбрасывает флаг, что подразумевает ответственность разработчика по обработке этой ситуации.
>
> Второй вариант реализации метода остановки (а также и приостановки) – сделать аналог interrupt, но руками. Т.е. организовать в собственной реализации потока флаги – на остановку и приостановку, – и выставлять их путем вызова методов извне. Методика действия та же – проверять установку флагов.